# Reading cookie values and storing them in an appropriate variable

Tags: javascript, servlets, cookies

Three cookies are sent from the servlet to the client with the entries of a form, name age and surname with the values entered by the user.

When the client sends back the cookies to the server I have to store:

- in the string variable name the value of the cookie named "name"
- in the int variable age the value of the cookie named "age"
- in thestring variable name the value of the cookie named "surname"

I have written this but it's not compiled and I don't know why:

> ```
> Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
> ```
>
> String name; int age; String surname;
>
> ```
>     for (int i=0; i<cookies.lenght; i++) {
> ```
>
> if (cookies[i].getName().equals("name"))
>
> ```
> name=cookies[i].getValue;
> ```
>
> else if (cookies[i].getName().equals("age"))
>
> ```
> age=cookies[i].getValue;
> ```
>
> else if (cookies[i].getName().equals("surname"))
>
> ```
>     surname=cookies[i].getValue;
> ```

There are 3 errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol name=cookies[i].getValue; symbol:   variable getValue   location: class Cookie

error: cannot find symbol age=cookies[i].getValue; location:class Cookie

error: cannot find symbol  surname=cookies[i].getValue;  symbol: variable getValue    location: class Cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

getValue is a member function (or method), not a member variable. So it needs parenthesis.

```
surname = cookies[i].getValue();
```

You also got your t and h reversed in `cookies.length` in your loop.

Comment: really don't know how to thank you. thank you very much. You saved me. It's two hours that I'm trying to solve this.